# Have matlab accept a state change with a given probability

Tags: matlab, state, probability

I have a state S that needs to change to state S' with a probability of Acceptance Pa. I've computed the probability of acceptance, and I have the two states (column vectors of 3 numbers each). I want to tell matlab to accept the change from S to S' with probability Pa.

Note: this is going to be inside a loop, and for each iteration Pa is computed and S changes to S' with probability Pa.

Help is appreciated

edit: here's what I have so far. there is a matrix of all 35 possible states (Pool). S' is Sn here.

```
S = [5;5;5];
indexn = randi(35);
Sn = Pool(:,indexn);
```

Cost is calculated here

```
PA = exp(-deltacost/k*T);
```

The next step would be to change S to Sn with probability PA. I might be overthinking this, but I don't know how to change it.

Comment: Try it yourself first, and post a short piece of code if you have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
if Pa<rand()
    do the change
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do a specific action with a specific probability is as follows:

1. Compute the probability with which the action should be done (`PA` in your case).
2. Draw a value from a [uniform probability distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29), let's call it `R`.
3. Check whether `R` is smaller than `PA`. This will be true with a probability exactly equal to `PA`. Execute the action in this case.

Final hint:
The Matlab function to draw a sample from a uniform distribution is `rand`.